# ¿Cómo hacer contenido editable, draggable y autoajustable en un CMS?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, html5

Estoy haciendo un CMS propio (a puro código PHP, nada de frameworks) para administrar el contenido de mi web.

En una sección de la web, se hará una especie de blog. En el panel de administración, este contenido debo agregarlo de forma dinámica, insertando texto e imágenes y tener la opción de mover este contenido, ubicar cada elemento donde quiera y poder ajustar su tamaño. Cada elemento debe ser editable (principalmente el texto) y al final cuando tenga el diseño definitivo, darle a la opción publicar (aun no está hecha esta funcionalidad) y que aparezca en la parte de mi página destinada para este contenido.

He intentado utilizar un poco de JavaScript para lograrlo, pero algunos cosas no funcionan bien. Por ejemplo, el contenido es editable pero para activarlo hay que darle con el click derecho del rato encima, la idea es que se active la edición cuando se le de doble click y poder ampliar o reducir el tamaño de las imágenes y el texto, ajustándolo por sus bordes (algo parecido a las funciones de Word para ajustar imágenes).

Este es mi código hasta ahora:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $("#addNewImageBlg").click(function() {

    var image_box = "<div id='img_box1'  class='ui-widget-content draggable' style='width: 300px;'><img id='img_drag1' width='20%' height='20%' src='preview image'/></div>";
    $("#main_col_blog_results").append(image_box);

    $(".ui-widget-content").draggable(); // initialize again

  });


  $("#btnAddTitlesBlog").click(function() {

    var title = $("#blog_titles").val();

    var letterS = $("#size_letter").val();
    var weight = $("#weight_letters").val();
    var styles = $("#style_letters").val();


    var weight_CSS = "";
    var styles_CSS = "";

    if (weight == "NOT") {
      weight_CSS = "normal";
    } else {
      weight_CSS = "bold";
    }


    if (styles == "NOT") {
      styles_CSS = "initial";
    } else {
      styles_CSS = "italic";
    }

    var content = "<div id='title1'  class='ui-widget-content draggable' style='float: left; margin-left: 30px; margin-right: 30px; margin-top: 30px;'><h5 contenteditable='true' style='font-size: " + letterS + "px; font-weight: " + weight_CSS + "; font-style: " + styles_CSS + ";'>" + title + "</h5></div>";

    $("#main_col_blog_results").append(content);

    $(".ui-widget-content").draggable(); // initialize again

  });


  $("#btnAddTextsBlog").click(function() {

    var texts = $("#blog_text").val();

    var content2 = "<div id='text1' class='ui-widget-content draggable' style='float: left; margin-left: 30px; margin-right: 30px; margin-top: 30px; display: block;'><p contenteditable='true' style='font-size: 18px;'>" + texts + "</p></div>";

    $("#main_col_blog_results").append(content2);

    $(".ui-widget-content").draggable(); // initialize again

  });


  $(".ui-widget-content").draggable();

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" />



<!-- /.card-header -->
<div class="card-body">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-2">
      <form role="form" method="POST" name="" id="" action="#" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <div class="form-group">
          <label class="control-label">Upload an Image </label>
          <input class="form-control" type="file" name="img_input" id="img_input" required>
        </div>
        <div class="tile-footer">
          <button class="btn btn-primary" type="button" id="addNewImageBlg"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-lg fa-check-circle"></i>Add</button>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
        </div>
      </form>
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-2">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label class="control-label">Add Title</label>
        <input class="form-control" type="text" name="blog_titles" id="blog_titles" required>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label class="control-label">Letter Size</label>
        <select id="size_letter">
          <option value="10">10</option>
          <option value="12">12</option>
          <option value="14">14</option>
          <option value="16">16</option>
          <option value="18">18</option>
          <option value="20">20</option>
          <option value="22" selected>22</option>
          <option value="24">24</option>
          <option value="26">26</option>
          <option value="28">28</option>
          <option value="39">30</option>
        </select>
      </div>
      <style type="text/css">
        #ksjhfkd {
          font-style: :
        }
      </style>

      <div class="form-group">
        <label class="control-label">Bold</label>
        <input type="checkbox" name="weight_letters" id="weight_letters" value="NOT">
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label class="control-label">Italic</label>
        <input type="checkbox" name="style_letters" id="style_letters" value="NOT">
      </div>

      <div class="tile-footer">
        <button class="btn btn-primary" type="button" id="btnAddTitlesBlog"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-lg fa-check-circle"></i>Add</button>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-4">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label class="control-label">Text </label>
        <textarea class="form-control" type="text" name="blog_text" id="blog_text" required></textarea>
      </div>
      <div class="tile-footer">
        <button class="btn btn-primary" type="button" id="btnAddTextsBlog"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-lg fa-check-circle"></i>Add</button>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
<!-- /.card-body -->
</div>
<!-- /.card -->

</div>
<!-- ./col -->
</div>
<!-- /.row -->

<div class="row">
  <div class="col-lg-12 col-12">
    <div class="card" id="BlogEditorOptions">
      <div class="card-header">
        <h3 class="card-title">Blog Section Results</h3>
      </div>
      <!-- /.card-header -->
      <div class="card-body">
        <div class="row" id="main_row_blog_results">
          <div class="col-md-12" id="main_col_blog_results">

          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <!-- /.card-body -->
    </div>
    <!-- /.card -->

  </div>
  <!-- ./col -->
</div>
```

Me gustaría saber cómo podría hacer el contenido editable al darle doble click (y no con click derecho del ratón) y autoajustar los tamaños de los elementos.

Cualquier ayuda o sugerencia que puedan darme ya que es la primera vez que intento hacer un editor de este tipo.

Comment: Reconocer un doble click es un poco complicado. Para esto necesitas utilizar `setTimeout` para ignorar el primer click en el caso en el cual hay un segundo click en un intervalo de tiempo dado. Recomiendo leer esta respuesta en el SO en inglés.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5497073/how-to-differentiate-single-click-event-and-double-click-event No creo que necesites entender ingles para entender de que va

Answer (score 3):

Con jQuery UI, además de tener el [`draggable`](http://api.jqueryui.com/draggable/) que ya usas para mover el elemento por pantalla, también tienes el [`resizable`](http://api.jqueryui.com/resizable/) para poder cambiar el tamaño del elemento. Entonces para ajustar el tamaño de los elementos podrías llamar a `resizable()` en los mismos sitios que haces la llamada a `draggable()`:

```
$(".ui-widget-content").draggable().resizable();
```

El otro problema es que con el draggable/droppable de jQuery UI el botón principal va a dejarte de funcionar para el `contenteditable` y por eso te ves obligado a usar el izquierdo. Lo cual es un problema no sólo para entrar en el modo de edición del `contenteditable` sino también por ejemplo si quieres seleccionar texto dentro de elemento que estás editando (porque se va a hacer drag-and-drop del elemento en lugar de seleccionar texto de dentro, por ejemplo).

Una posible solución sería crear dos controladores de evento. Uno para el doble click (`dblclick`) y otro para cuando el elemento pierda el foco (`blur`). En el `dblclick` forzarías el foco en el elemento (de ese modo entrará en modo editable) y pondrías el `draggable` en pausa (algo que puedes hacer con la propiedad [`disable`](http://api.jqueryui.com/draggable/#method-disable)). Y en el `blur` volverías a activar el `draggable` con la opción [`enable`](http://api.jqueryui.com/draggable/#method-enable).

Enfocar un elemento que no es accionable no es trivial (hay bastantes preguntas sobre el tema en Stack Overflow en inglés). Estuve mirando algunas opciones en [ésta](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2388164/3695983), pero todas tenían algún algo que no funcionaba. Finalmente opté por seleccionar el primer elemento hijo y hacer `focus()` en él (algo que no funcionaría si el `contenteditable` no tuviera hijos, pero no es el caso).

Aquí puedes ver el código con los cambios:

> Nota: he añadido uno de los temas de jQuery UI para que se vea mejor los elementos que pueden cambiar tamaño (con borde y un icono en una esquina). No he corregido posibles errores en el código, me he limitado a incluir los dos cambios especificados arriba.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $("#addNewImageBlg").click(function() {

    var image_box = "<div id='img_box1'  class='ui-widget-content draggable' style='width: 300px;'><img id='img_drag1' width='20%' height='20%' src='preview image'/></div>";
    $("#main_col_blog_results").append(image_box);

    $(".ui-widget-content").draggable().resizable(); // initialize again

  });


  $("#btnAddTitlesBlog").click(function() {

    var title = $("#blog_titles").val();

    var letterS = $("#size_letter").val();
    var weight = $("#weight_letters").val();
    var styles = $("#style_letters").val();


    var weight_CSS = "";
    var styles_CSS = "";

    if (weight == "NOT") {
      weight_CSS = "normal";
    } else {
      weight_CSS = "bold";
    }


    if (styles == "NOT") {
      styles_CSS = "initial";
    } else {
      styles_CSS = "italic";
    }

    var content = "<div id='title1'  class='ui-widget-content draggable' style='float: left; margin-left: 30px; margin-right: 30px; margin-top: 30px;'><h5 contenteditable='true' style='font-size: " + letterS + "px; font-weight: " + weight_CSS + "; font-style: " + styles_CSS + ";'>" + title + "</h5></div>";

    $("#main_col_blog_results").append(content);

    $(".ui-widget-content").draggable().resizable(); // initialize again

  });


  $("#btnAddTextsBlog").click(function() {

    var texts = $("#blog_text").val();

    var content2 = "<div id='text1' class='ui-widget-content draggable' style='float: left; margin-left: 30px; margin-right: 30px; margin-top: 30px; display: block;'><p contenteditable='true' style='font-size: 18px;'>" + texts + "</p></div>";

    $("#main_col_blog_results").append(content2);

    $(".ui-widget-content").draggable().resizable(); // initialize again

  });


  $(".ui-widget-content").draggable().resizable();

});

$("#main_col_blog_results").on("dblclick", ".ui-widget-content", function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  $(this).draggable('disable');
  this.querySelector(":scope > :first-child").focus();
});

$("#main_col_blog_results").on("blur", ".ui-widget-content", function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  $(this).draggable('enable');
});
```

```css
.resizable {
  border: 1px dotted gray;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" />


<!-- /.card-header -->
<div class="card-body">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-2">
      <form role="form" method="POST" name="" id="" action="#" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <div class="form-group">
          <label class="control-label">Upload an Image </label>
          <input class="form-control" type="file" name="img_input" id="img_input" required>
        </div>
        <div class="tile-footer">
          <button class="btn btn-primary" type="button" id="addNewImageBlg"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-lg fa-check-circle"></i>Add</button>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
        </div>
      </form>
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-2">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label class="control-label">Add Title</label>
        <input class="form-control" type="text" name="blog_titles" id="blog_titles" required>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label class="control-label">Letter Size</label>
        <select id="size_letter">
          <option value="10">10</option>
          <option value="12">12</option>
          <option value="14">14</option>
          <option value="16">16</option>
          <option value="18">18</option>
          <option value="20">20</option>
          <option value="22" selected>22</option>
          <option value="24">24</option>
          <option value="26">26</option>
          <option value="28">28</option>
          <option value="39">30</option>
        </select>
      </div>
      <style type="text/css">
        #ksjhfkd {
          font-style: :
        }
      </style>

      <div class="form-group">
        <label class="control-label">Bold</label>
        <input type="checkbox" name="weight_letters" id="weight_letters" value="NOT">
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label class="control-label">Italic</label>
        <input type="checkbox" name="style_letters" id="style_letters" value="NOT">
      </div>

      <div class="tile-footer">
        <button class="btn btn-primary" type="button" id="btnAddTitlesBlog"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-lg fa-check-circle"></i>Add</button>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-4">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label class="control-label">Text </label>
        <textarea class="form-control" type="text" name="blog_text" id="blog_text" required></textarea>
      </div>
      <div class="tile-footer">
        <button class="btn btn-primary" type="button" id="btnAddTextsBlog"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-lg fa-check-circle"></i>Add</button>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
<!-- /.card-body -->
</div>
<!-- /.card -->

</div>
<!-- ./col -->
</div>
<!-- /.row -->

<div class="row">
  <div class="col-lg-12 col-12">
    <div class="card" id="BlogEditorOptions">
      <div class="card-header">
        <h3 class="card-title">Blog Section Results</h3>
      </div>
      <!-- /.card-header -->
      <div class="card-body">
        <div class="row" id="main_row_blog_results">
          <div class="col-md-12" id="main_col_blog_results">

          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <!-- /.card-body -->
    </div>
    <!-- /.card -->

  </div>
  <!-- ./col -->
</div>
```

Comment: Excelente como siempre señor Alvaro Montoro, muy util su ejemplo que realmente me ha servido muchísimo, lo he adaptado y expandandido en mi pequeño CMS y realmente me ha ayudado.